# Integral analog of geometric series

Tags: integration, power-series

We all know that
$$
\frac{1}{1-z}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty z^m\ ,
$$
for $|z|<1$. The challenge I would like to pose is: find (possibly as *simple* and *elegant*) *integral* representations (as many as you can) for $$\frac{1}{1-z}$$ (possibly limited to $z\in\mathbb{R}$ and not necessarily for $|z|<1$). I will start with one:
$$
\frac{1}{1-z}=\int_0^\infty ds\ e^{-s(1-z)}\qquad\text{for }z\in\mathbb{R}\text{ and }z<1.
$$
Please help me find the most stunningly simple and beautiful integral analogs of the geometric series.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{z-1}^{+\infty} x^{-2} dx$$
$$\int_{0}^{1} x^{-z} dx $$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x^2\sqrt{\frac{1-z}{2\pi}}e^{\displaystyle-\frac{x^2(1-z)}{2}}dx $$